# How to link popups to buttons generated from a for loop? - kivy

Tags: for-loop, kivy, popupwindow

I am trying to make an app that generates a list of open restaurants depending on user inputted time. Clicking on each restaurant button should then bring the user to a popup containing specific information tied to the restaurant.

The buttons were generated using a for loop, but I am having issues making the each popup title the text of the button it came from. The code I have so far only sets the popup title to the text of the last button generated.

```
nameres=0
class openedpopup(FloatLayout): #the content of the popup 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(openedpopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.list_of_openrest()

    def list_of_openrest(self):
        global restaurants 
        global nameres
        count=0

        for key in restaurants:
            if restaurants.get(key)[0]=="Open":
                openedpopupbut = Button(text=key,...)
                openedpopupbut.bind(on_press=self.btn)
                self.add_widget(openedpopupbut)
                count+=1
                nameres=openedpopupbut.text

    def btn(self, instance):
        global nameres
        store_popup_open(nameres)

def store_popup_open(nameres):   # to determine the size and formatting of popup
    show = storepopupopen()      # class containing widgets present in popup
    popupWindow = Popup(title= nameres,\
                        content=show,...)
    popupWindow.open()        

...
```

I am a kivy beginner and am unsure of how to approach this problem. I understand that it is common to use ids in the kv file to reference variables but I am unsure of whether it will work for my case because of the loop.

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify something in the kv file. So doing this in the code is ok.

Did you try

```
def btn(self, instance):
    store_popup_open(instance.text)
```

Comment: I get the error " AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'text' ", I have also tried returning `openedpopupbut.text` in the method `list_of_openrest` and then writing `store_popup_open(self.list_of_openrest)`. That doesn't work as well as the object class is method. Thanks for the suggestion though!